# Enabled flags to prevent anonymous access to pipes and shares not working

Tags: windows, pipe, gpo, network-share, anonymous-access

We have applied the following settings into a GPO and pushed it to a staging server and successfully prevented anonymous access to pipes and shares. However when we apply the same to our internal production machines we are still able to access the IPC$ share anonymo[image]

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the server was of course the solution.